# Knockout.js Workflow with Mapping plugin

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm not sure I understand the workflow Knockout.js follows internally.  I have a ViewModel that is defined dynamically, using the mapping plugin.  Its shape is:

```
{ current: { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', id: 0 }
, ids:     [1,2,3,4,5] 
}
```

Each of those `ids` corresponds to a value that can belong in `current`.  Now, the complication comes in because in the initial ajax request to populate my viewModel, the server responds with `current: null`.  I have written code to take the first `id` out of the list of `ids` and run another ajax query to populate `current`.  That looks like this:

```
var ViewModel = function (data) {
  var self = this;
  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);

  self.head = function () {
    if (self.promptIds().length != 0) {
      var nextId = _.head(self.promptIds());
      self.promptIds(_.tail(self.promptIds()));
      $.getJSON("my-url" + "/" + nextId, function (data) {
        self.current(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));
      });
    }
  }
}


$('document').ready ( function () {
  $.getJSON("view-model-route", function (data) {
    viewModel = new ViewModel(data);
    viewModel.head();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
  });
});
```

Notice that in the second block, I create a new `ViewModel` object and I call `head()` on it.  Once the `viewModel.current()` object is populated, I call `ko.applyBindings` on the complete `viewModel`.  I can confirm that when all the dust settles, `viewModel.current` is not `null`.  But I am still getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Unable to parse bindings.
  Bindings value: text: current().foo
  Message: Cannot read property 'foo' of null
```

Am I trying to do something Knockout wasn't designed to do?  Do I need another layer of abstraction?  How would you approach this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bindings are first evaluated when you call `ko.applyBindings`.

So if your `current` property contains `null` by that time then this it is normal that you get an `Cannot read property 'foo' of null` exception.

There are multiple solution to this problem:

- Initialize `current` with an empty object, so the `current().foo` will be parsed correctly (but its value be `undefined`):

  ```
  viewModel = new ViewModel(data);
  viewModel.head();
  viewModel.current({});
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
  ```
- You can add an extra condition in your binding to check that `current` has some value:

  ```
  <input type="text" data-bind="value: current() && current().foo" />
  ```
- Or probably the best and most recommended option is to use the [`with` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html) if you are dealing with nested proeprties:

  ```
  <!-- ko with: current -->
      <input type="text" data-bind="value: foo" />
  <!-- /ko -->
  ```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/E6qWX/).

Comment: That's the thing, though.  I was calling viewModel.head (which populates current) before calling applyBindings.

Comment: Yes, you are calling `viewModel.head` before `ko.applyBindings`, but `head` **does not** directly set the `current`. The `current` is set in a `$.getJSON` callback which is **aync**. So setting the `current` will eventually happen only after the `ko.applyBindings` so you need to use one of the above mentioned techniques to fix it.

Comment: Okay, I understand now.  I didn't realize race conditions were possible in JavaScript.  Thank you!