# Knockout options with forms not binding to model

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am having problems with KnockoutJS and the options binding.

What I'm trying to achieve is functionality to display a form based on selected option with the options binding.

The odd thing is that it works with the first form-field but the model is not value binded for the others.

Here is my markup:

```
<div id="page">
    <form data-bind="submit: executeTask">
        <select data-bind="options: availableTasks, value: selectedTask, optionsText: 'description',  optionsCaption: 'Select...',"></select>
        <div data-bind="visible: selectedTask">
            <input type="text" data-bind="value:selectedTask().assignee">
            <input type="text" data-bind="value:selectedTask().estimatedTime">
        </div>
        <button class="btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
    $(function() {
        var taskController = new TaskController(document.getElementById("page"));
    });
</script>
```

And here is my model:

```
(function () {

    function Task(id, description) {
        var model = this;
        model.id = ko.observable(id);
        model.description = ko.observable(description);
        model.assignee = ko.observable();
        model.estimatedTime = ko.observable();
    };

    window.TaskController = function (element) {
        var model = this;

        model.availableTasks = [
        new Task("0", "Laundry"),
        new Task("1", "Dinner")];

        model.selectedTask = ko.observable();

        model.executeTask = function (form) {
            console.log(ko.toJSON(model.selectedTask()));
        };


        ko.applyBindings(this, element);
    };
})();
```

The full code can be found at the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/17057/

As you can see in the console, only the "assignee" property is getting binded, but not the "estimatedTime" property.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Bj Blazkowicz

Comment: Please check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24000573/knockout-js-workflow-with-mapping-plugin/24001654#24001654 your problem is exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks man, the with binding did it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1:

Replace the visible binding with an `if` binding:

```
<div data-bind="visible: selectedTask">
```

Should be

```
<div data-bind="if: selectedTask">
```

**Explanation**

You were getting an error because it could not find `selectedTask().assignee`. The problem was that `selectedTask()` returned `undefined` at page load. Even though the inputs were not visible due to `visible: selectedTask`, the binding was interpreted.

With the `if` binding, what is inside the tag is ignored when `selectedTask()` returns `undefined`.

### Solution 2:

As [nemesv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/872395/nemesv) pointed out, you can use the `with` binding (see [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24000573/knockout-js-workflow-with-mapping-plugin/24001654#24001654)):

```
<div data-bind="with: selectedTask">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: assignee">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: estimatedTime">
</div>
```

Comment: @BjBlazkowicz Sorry, I answered too quickly :) Answer updated.